# Why does 2 Peter 2:5 refer to Noah as "the eighth"?

Tags: authorial-intent, 2-peter, noah

[2 Peter 2:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+peter+2%3A5&version=MOUNCE) (Mounce Reverse Interlinear New Testament) :

> and if he did not spare the ancient world (but preserved Noah, **the eighth**, a herald of righteousness) when he brought the deluge on an ungodly world;

The phrase in bold is from the Greek *ogdoon*/*ogdoos*

Strong's Concordance assigns this word [#3590](https://biblehub.com/greek/3590.htm):

- **definition**: "the eighth"
- **usage**: the eighth, one of eight, with seven others

Referring to dozens of English translations, the oldest and newer, and a few intended for converts from Judaism, reveals that almost every usage is of the "one of eight" or "with seven others" variety, and usually with the added (but not indicated) word "people". This makes the term a simple reference to the whole family that entered the Ark (four men and their wives).

A few versions, mainly archaic or pure literal translations, leave it as "the eighth" with no clarification.

The Englishman's Concordance gives examples of this word followed with "person" or "day".

A few explanations can be found online that attempt make this term a reference to the idea of Noah being a sort of re-beginning, since the Old Testament has descriptions of various events that last seven days, so the eighth day would be a new start.  Or possibly an event occurs after seven months of something, so it may be considered the eighth.

Or could this be a reference of some kind to the idea that there were seven pairs of each clean animal admitted to the Ark, so humanity is the eighth? Or that they all waited in the Ark for seven days so this re-beginning began with flooding on the eighth?

The entire chapter is about how God destroyed all the people except Noah and his family, then mentions saving Lot from Sodom but doesn't mention his family (Lot was not called "the fourth").  If making the argument this is because Lot's family wasn't righteous, they were just along with Lot, then include in your reasoning why Noah's family was as righteous as Noah.

If making the argument that Noah was the eighth person in a line (type or genealogy), thoroughly explain your reasoning why the first person in that line is significant.

Comment: There is the question of whether αλλ ογδοον νωε  is a matter of a cardinal number ('number eight Noah' - a question of how many in total were saved) or an ordinal number ('eighth Noah') in reference to him being the last to enter the ark. Up-voted +1.

Comment: @Nigel, I had looked for specific reference to Noah being the last (eighth) to enter but couldn't find any.

Comment: @Nigel I found an ordinal reference for Noah being the eighth person, counting back generations then making a weak argument for why the first (not Adam obviously) was chosen. So I put that clarifier near the end of my question.

Comment: I think all the evidence points to the 'eighth' (ordinal) as drawing attention to Noah being the last to enter the ark, and thus none other were saved, since none else followed him.

Comment: @Nigel, I'd like it, except all verses either treat the whole group as one, or that Noah was the one so the family was brought along with him. Is there evidence of a custom of the times that the head of the family enters a doorway last?

Comment: The text focuses on 'the eighth' and Noah is that eighth. If a 'custom' was relevant, the text would inform of us of that. The text does not. You are missing the obvious, in my own view.

Comment: The problem is in the translation. Noah, his wife and three sons with their wives are those eight. 
“The Noah’s eight.”

Answer (score 1):

> The entire chapter is about how God destroyed all the people except Noah and his family, then mentions saving Lot from Sodom but doesn't mention his family. If making the argument this is because lot's family wasn't righteous, they were just along with Lot, then include in your reasoning why Noah's family was as righteous as Noah.

Hope my basic understanding could help:

> This is the story of Noah. He had three sons, Shem, Ham, and Japheth. Noah had no faults and was the only good man of his time. He lived in fellowship with God, Genesis 6:9‭-‬10 GNT

> The Lord said to Noah, “Go into the boat with your whole family; I have found that you are the only one in all the world who does what is right. Genesis 7:1 GNT

The text repeat that Noah is the only one and with Noah's righteous, saves his family of 8.

> The two men said to Lot, “If you have anyone else here—sons, daughters, sons-in-law, or any other relatives living in the city—get them out of here, Genesis 19:12 GNT

> Then Lot went to the men that his daughters were going to marry, and said, “Hurry up and get out of here; the Lord is going to destroy this place.” But they thought he was joking. Genesis 19:14 GNT

For Lot's case, we dont see any text on Lot that says he is righteous. So on what account Lot's family got rescued?

Let us read the following:

> Abraham said, “Please don't be angry, Lord, and I will speak only once more. What if only ten are found?” He said, “I will not destroy it if there are ten.” Genesis 18:32 GNT

The last conversation we understood that there is no righteous people in the 2 cities and Abraham cant reduce less than 8 (the lease figure from the last catastrophic event:flood).

Lot's family is saved due to Abraham's credit:

> I have chosen him in order that he may command his sons and his descendants to obey me and to do what is right and just. If they do, I will do everything for him that I have promised.” Genesis 18:19 GNT

We know Lot and Abraham came out from Haran and probably Abraham shared his view of God and Lot might have adopted monotheism from Abraham.

Lot's 2 son-in-law choose not to escape hence got their lunch box and left the world. Lot's wife did not obey the command not to look back and got her lunch box also.

> Then one of the angels said, “Run for your lives! Don't look back and don't stop in the valley. Run to the hills, so that you won't be killed.” Genesis 19:17 GNT

So overall context, we can be sure that our righteous (doing what's right and Just) status with God of Israel can save our family in time of distress.

Comment: Thank You @VNPython. I was attempting to keep the focus on Noah as "the eighth", so if that meant "a family of eight" why wasn't Lot called "the fourth" in that passage (meaning that eight doesn't seem to refer to size of the family).  I have clarified my question, thank you!

Comment: God did not spare the ancient world, but brought the flood on the world of godless people; the only ones he saved were Noah, who preached righteousness, and seven other people. 2 Peter 2:5 GNT // i dont see other translation use that word. i always check other translation to know the overall context. i am no expert nor i focus on paul's saying. He has proven himself as a non observance jew (many areas in question).

Answer (score 0):

“and delivered righteous Lot, who was oppressed by the filthy conduct of the wicked (for that righteous man, dwelling among them, tormented his righteous soul from day to day by seeing and hearing their lawless deeds)—”
(‭‭II Peter‬ ‭2:7-8‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

- Lot was righteous too

“Now it came to pass, when men began to multiply on the face of the earth, and daughters were born to them, that the sons of God saw the daughters of men, that they were beautiful; and they took wives for themselves of all whom they chose.”
(‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:1-2‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

- Fallen angels were contaminating the bloodline, God had promised a savior through the seed of the woman (Genesis 3:15)

“This is the genealogy of Noah. Noah was a just man, perfect in his generations. Noah walked with God.”
(‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:9‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

- Noah did not have a contaminated bloodline

“But as the days of Noah were, so also will the coming of the Son of Man be.”
(‭‭Matthew‬ ‭24:37‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

- We will be going back to those conditions before the second coming

“Now Enoch, the seventh from Adam, prophesied about these men also, saying, “Behold, the Lord comes with ten thousands of His saints, to execute judgment on all, to convict all who are ungodly among them of all their ungodly deeds which they have committed in an ungodly way, and of all the harsh things which ungodly sinners have spoken against Him.””
(‭‭Jude‬ ‭1:14-15‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

- Here the type is confirmed, Enoch was the seventh and he was “taken” (Genesis 5:24)

““Son of man, when a land sins against Me by persistent unfaithfulness, I will stretch out My hand against it; I will cut off its supply of bread, send famine on it, and cut off man and beast from it. Even if these three men, Noah, Daniel, and Job, were in it, they would deliver only themselves by their righteousness,” says the Lord God.”
‭‭(Ezekiel‬ ‭14:13-14‬ ‭NKJV‬‬)

Comment: Thank You for helping @Tyler.  I don't see an actual answer to my question. Enoch is seventh "from Adam" but that would make Noah tenth, not eighth.  And my reference to Lot wasn't really to compare the two except to say Lot wasn't written as "the Fourth" (+ wife & 2 daughters) to match Noah (+wife and 3 sons plus wives).  Eventually a moderator will come along and point out the need for answering the actual question.  But it is good you used actual references in your answer!

Comment: I’m sorry for not clarifying more, the Holy Spirit highlighted in that passage him being the eighth to my understanding so it would lead us to him being a type. 2 Peter deals with the second coming, so he was bringing us back to those passages like Jesus. Those numbers “seventh” and “eighth” refer to days of creation in reference to prophecy. I left out the part about the harpazo due to board rules.

Answer (score -1):

Let's try this for a minute. I have looked at the Melchizedek priesthood going from the days of Moses. Going back to trying to figure out who was a Melchizedek
priest. Also looking at who taught the Aaronic priesthood how to be excepted by YHWH. Remember that only a priest can perform a sinful sacrifice of blood. We see that even the King of Israel could not perform a blood sacrifice that Elohim would except. Reference to King Saul Elohim s consecrated. Now back to Noah he is a Melchizedek priest and does an animal sacrifice when they come out of the Ark.Noah is the 8th Melchizedek priest from Adam who also was the first Melchizedek human priest anointed by the first and the last Melchizedek priest of the heavenly Tabernacle.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).